# SQL begin end print

Tags: sql

I have following tsql code in sql server 2008:

```
    declare @ID INT  
    SET @ID = 0
    IF (@ID IS NOT NULL OR @ID <> 0) 
    begin
      print 'ID is not 0 or null'
    end
```

Since @ID is 0, why does it even get into the begin end ... It should not.

Comment: It meets the `@ID IS NOT NULL` part. `True or x` equals `true`. Guess you probably wanted `and` but just `if (@ID <> 0)` is sufficient as if `@ID IS NULL` that isn't `true` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have better luck using `and` instead

```
declare @ID INT  
    SET @ID = 0
    IF (@ID IS NOT NULL AND @ID <> 0) 
    begin
      print 'ID is not 0 or null'
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a case of meaning `AND` and not `OR`. Then it should have the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The `@ID is not Null` so it meets the requirement for half of your `OR` statement.  If you want it to not hit the print, then you should use `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition @ID iS NOT NULL is true so it's going inside and printing the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (@ID IS NOT NULL OR @ID <> 0)
```

Since @ID is not null, it enters the begin-end block.